# How to optimize sql requests?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How to optimize requests? Hello there is a chat which consists of the following tables

Chat rooms

```
id, type(USER_TO_USER, USER_TO_SHOP, USER_TO_PLATFORM), name
```

Chat Room Members room_participants

```
id, participantType (USER, SHOP, PLATFORM), participant_id
```

list of messages

```
room_messages - id, participant_id, text, is_read
```

Additionally:

users table

```
id, first_name, last_name, image, image_src
```

shops table

```
id, name, logo, logo_src
```

The task is:

Display a list of the room with its members for a specific user + the last message of the room (as VK)
the first thing I did was a request to get all the rooms: in which a specific user is a member

```
select r.id, r.name from rooms as r
left join room_participants rp on r.id = rp.room_id
where rp."participantType" = 'USER' and rp.participant_id = 1
```

the second request I make is to get members (other than the current user) for each room

```
select
    room_id,
    case
        when "participantType" = 'USER' and participant_id != 1 then (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = participant_id)
        when "participantType" = 'SHOP' then (SELECT id FROM shops WHERE id = participant_id)
    END AS participant_id,

    case
        when "participantType" = 'USER' and participant_id != 1 then (SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id = participant_id)
        when "participantType" = 'SHOP' then (SELECT name FROM shops WHERE id = participant_id)
    END AS participant_name,

    case
        when "participantType" = 'USER' and participant_id != 1 then (SELECT image FROM users WHERE id = participant_id)
        when "participantType" = 'SHOP' then (SELECT logo FROM shops WHERE id = participant_id)
    END AS participant_image,

    case
        when "participantType" = 'USER' and participant_id != 1 then (SELECT image_src FROM users WHERE id = participant_id)
        when "participantType" = 'SHOP' then (SELECT logo_src FROM shops WHERE id = participant_id)
    END AS participant_image_src

from room_participants

where room_id in (1)
```

The question is, how can these queries be optimized?

and the second question, if these are optimal queries, then how with the last query, how to remove empty lines

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using joins instead sub-queries:

```
select
    room_id,
    COALESCE(u.id, s.id) AS participant_id,
    COALESCE(u.first_name, s.name) AS participant_name,
    COALESCE(u.image, s.logo) AS participant_image,
    COALESCE(u.image_src, s.logo_src) AS participant_image_src

from room_participants p
left join shops s
    on p.participant_id = s.id
    and p.participantType = 'SHOP'
left join users u
    on p.participant_id = u.id
    and p.participantType = 'USER'
    AND p.participant_id != 1

where room_id in (1)
    AND COALESCE(u.id, s.id) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: how to get rid of empty lines?

Comment: @Aslero check the edit - just filter them.

Answer (score 0):

use union with inner join for better performance compare using left join

```
select rp.room_id, u.id as participant_id, u.first_name as participant_name, u.image as participant_image, 
    u.image_src participant_image_src
from room_participants rp
join users u on u.id = rp.participant_id
where rp.room_id in (1)
and rp.participantType = 'USER' and rp.participant_id != 1

UNION ALL 

select rp.room_id, s.id as participant_id, s.name as participant_name, s.logo as participant_image, 
    s.logo_src participant_image_src
from room_participants rp
join shops s on s.id = rp.participant_id
where rp.room_id in (1)
and rp.participantType = 'SHOP' and rp.participant_id != 1
```